# jQuery: How do I select text in a div and add tags around it?

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to do the following:

```
<div class="test">text</div>
```

I'm trying to write jQuery that will select the text inside the div and change it to:

```
<div class="test"><span>test</span></div>
```

When I try this in jQuery:

```
$(".test").prepend("<span>");
$(".test").append("</span>");
```

It shows up in the HTML as:

```
<div class="test"><span/>test</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [wrapInner](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner) function.

```
$(".test").wrapInner("<span></span>");
```